# Неправильный ответ при формирование запроса с помощью Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Я разрабатываю API сервис на Ruby on Rails. Есть запрос на получение версии лаунчера.

Ответ должен быть таким:

```
{"version":"2.1"}
```

Но я получаю его таким:

```
{"version":"2.1","stat":null}
```

Вот мой запрос:

```
def launcher
   @launcher = Stat.select('value as version').where(stat: 'launcher_version').take
  render json: @launcher
end
```

Аналогичный запрос с помощью PHP работает без проблем

```
SELECT `value` as `version` FROM `stats` WHERE `stat` = 'launcher_version' LIMIT 1
```

Как убрать этот null?

Answer (score 1):

```
@launcher = { version: Stat.find_by_stat('launcher_version').value }
```